# Codecademy howOld syntax error at else if

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax

As a coding noob I am always struggling with syntax in my Javascript exercises in Codecademy.  This is my first problem I havent been able to solve without some internet search help - my apologies if this is already solved here.

I am usually a semi-colon away from solving it, but not this time (?).  Im attempting to accommodate 3 outcomes:

1. someone inputs a year in the future and I tell them their age in that year.
2. someone inputs a year before they were born and I give them the # of years until they were born.
3. someone inputs a year after they were born and I give them their age at that time.

I've spent too much time moving curly brackets and semi colons and I guess I just cant see the error.

```
const howOld = (age, year) =>

 {
  if 
    (year > 2019);
    let calculatedAge = ( year - 2019 + age );
  {
  return `You will be ${calculatedAge } in the year ${year}.`;

  } else if 
    (year < (2019-age));
    let calculatedAge = ( 2019 - year + age ); 
  {
  return `The year ${year } was ${calculatedAge } years before you were 
born.`;

  } else 
    let calculatedAge = ( year - 2019 + age );
  { 
  return `You were ${calculatedAge} in the year ${year}. `; 
  }

};

console.log(howOld(47,2000))
```

I am getting a syntax error at my 'else if' statement.

Comment: The semi-colon after `;` is not correct and also move all the `{}` one step up. Means `let calculatedAge = ...` should be in `{}`

Comment: This time it is too much of semi-colon. In JavaScript `if` expressions are not terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Not going to solve it for you, but I will provide some clues.  Remember, an "if" is just the start of a block, and it needs some kind of condition.  "If this, then that."  The "that" could be a list of things to do.  An "else" is the same idea - it's not any of the things in the "if" condition, so let's do some other stuff.

Also, the condition in an if statement doesn't mean anything all by itself, so there would be no reason to end that idea with a semicolon.

Comment: I recommend that you have a look at using `Prettier` code formatter which will assist formatting code so that it's easier to understand. It's available in VS Code and Atom.

Comment: Awesome help and quick too thank you! I messed up one my formula too, but that was easy to fix after I got the syntax lined up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it

```
    const howOld = (age, year) =>

 {
  if(year > 2019)
  {
    let calculatedAge = ( year - 2019 + age );
    return `You will be ${calculatedAge } in the year ${year}.`;

  } 
  else if(year < (2019-age))
  {  
    let calculatedAge = ( 2019 - year + age ); 
    return `The year ${year } was ${calculatedAge } years before you were born.`;
  } 
  else
  {
    let calculatedAge = ( year - 2019 + age ); 
    return `You were ${calculatedAge} in the year ${year}. `; 
  }

};

console.log(howOld(47,2000))
```

To explain your mistake, you had your if statement wrong
instead of having

```
if(condition){do}
```

you had

```
if(condition);do{do}
```

Comment: for more information you can check here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: I failed to include the let statement within the function body (or curly brackets) and i erroneously added semi colons at the end of my if statements.  Thanks!

Comment: no worries, good luck in your programming journey, I recommend reading https://www.w3schools.com/js/ it helps understanding JS and other languages

Answer (score 2):

You can change around your if/else statements a little bit. You were close, just had your conditions and brackets a little mixed up.

You want to make sure you have a syntax like this:

```
if (condition)
{
    // do something
} else if (condition)
{
    // do something else
}
```

Try this solution:

```
const howOld = (age, year) =>

{
  if (year > 2019)
  {
      let calculatedAge = ( year - 2019 + age );
      return `You will be ${calculatedAge } in the year ${year}.`;
  } else if (year < (2019-age))
  {
      let calculatedAge = ( 2019 - year + age ); 
      return `The year ${year } was ${calculatedAge } years before you were born.`;
  } else
  {
      let calculatedAge = ( year - 2019 + age );
      return `You were ${calculatedAge} in the year ${year}. `; 
  }

};

console.log(howOld(47,2000))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have small error in code that comes from unique style of yours. If we standardize the code we will see that there are excessive semicolons as well bracketing isn't correct.

```
const howOld = (age, year) => {
  if (year > 2019);
    let calculatedAge = ( year - 2019 + age );
  {
  return `You will be ${calculatedAge } in the year ${year}.`;

  } else if (year < (2019-age));
    let calculatedAge = ( 2019 - year + age );
  {
  return `The year ${year } was ${calculatedAge } years before you were born.`;

  } else
    let calculatedAge = ( year - 2019 + age );
  {
  return `You were ${calculatedAge} in the year ${year}. `;
  }

};
```

The correct version:

```
const howOld = (age, year) => {
    if (year > 2019){
      let calculatedAge = ( year - 2019 + age );
      return `You will be ${calculatedAge } in the year ${year}.`;
    } else if (year < (2019-age)) {
      let calculatedAge = ( 2019 - year + age );
      return `The year ${year } was ${calculatedAge } years before you were born.`;
    } else {
      let calculatedAge = ( year - 2019 + age );
      return `You were ${calculatedAge} in the year ${year}.`;
    }
  };
console.log(howOld(47,2000))
```